# Increment a number with a max length

Tags: javascript

Currently in my application I have an increment logic as below, and it fails now when `b` value above `9` (i.e `00010`, `00011`). As the limit is 4 digits which should become `0010`, `0011` and so on.

How can i make value to `0010` instead of `00010`

```
var b = 0; 
for (var p = 0; p < tabarray.length; p++)
{ 
   b = b + 1; 
   tabarray[p].ItemKey = "000" + b; 
}
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve] using the `<>` snippet editor. Use slice with a negative number to grab concatenated values from the end.

Comment: if(b>9) ==> "00"+b;

Comment: I think this is pretty much a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267283/how-can-i-create-a-zerofilled-value-using-javascript

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`String#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) and take only the last 4 digits.

```js
var b = 0; 

for (var p = 0; p < 10; p++) { 
    b = b + 1; 
    console.log(("000" + b).slice(-4));
}
```

Comment: How can i convert it back to integer from string. I am currently trying with parseint but it reduces the length from 0001 to 1.

Comment: `parseInt` converts a string to a number, and the number has no length. you can use either a string or a number, but not something between.